# Create a Multiple Choice Quiz with arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to create a quiz using a string array and a running score will be displayed, there will be one point added for each correct answer and once point subtracted for each wrong answer. I've got the first question working fine I just don't know how to do it for the next ones. I only have one submit button so all the code for the first question is connected to that button. How do I make it so when you submit your second answer it tells you its correct then moves on? 
I have been told a for loop would work well with this but I don't know how to implement it.

```
int score = 0;
int i = -1;
int a = 0;

string[] questions = new string[] { 
    "What is 9 cubed?", 
    "What is 6+3?", 
    "What type of animal is tuna sandwiches made from?", 
    "What is 18 backwards?" };

string[] answers = new string[] { 
"9", "81", "729", "2", "4", "2", 
"9", "1", "zebra", "aardvark", 
"fish", "gnu", "31", 
"81", "91", "88" };

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i < questions.Length)
    i++;
    //txtScore.Text = score;

    lblQuestion.Text = questions[i];

    radA.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radB.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radC.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radD.Text = answers[a];
    a++;

    btnStart.Visible = false;
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
    btnSubmit.Visible = true;
    btnSubmit.Enabled = true;

}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (i == 0 && radB.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");
            score++;
            txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
            btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
            btnSubmit.Visible = false;
            btnStart.Visible = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Text = "Next";
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
            score--;
        }
```

Comment: did you want the score to be updated as the user inputs the answer? or only when they click submit?

Comment: if the user gives one wrong answer he should not be allowed further right?

Comment: @Catalyst it's radio buttons so the way the user can input an answer is by clicking the submit button :)

Comment: @Sudhakar No, they can still continue to the rest of the quiz I suppose but they loss a point for every incorrect submission

Comment: what should happen when user press submit?

Comment: it is also not good practice to validate on just selecting by radio button as he does not have an option to select other if he selects one.

Comment: @Sudhakar A message box with a 'correct' or 'incorrect' notice; A point is either rewarded or deducted; the submit button disappear and  a 'next question' button appears. Once that is clicked the new question and answers will show - this is where I run into problems. Also I know about the radio button issue, I'm still trying to work out how I can fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problems :**
here you have hardcoded answer with radio button b value as below:

```
if (i == 0 && radB.Checked)
```

it will only check answer with radio button b and it will only work for first question.

you are not continuing this process for rest of the Questions.

**solution:**
i have added one strng array which contain all quiz answers for your questions.
so when user press submit button it will verify with respective answer and continue the same process till the end.

**code as below:**

```
int score = 0;
int i = -1;
int a = 0;

string[] questions = new string[]
{
    "What is 9 cubed?", "What is 6+3?", 
    "What type of animal is tuna sandwiches made from?",
    "What is 18 backwards?"
};

string[] answers = new string[] {
   "9", "81", "729", "2", 
   "4", "2", "9", "1", 
   "zebra", "aardvark", "fish", "gnu", 
   "31", "81", "91", "88"
};

string [] quizAnswers=new string[]{"729","9","aardvark","81"};
private     void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i < questions.Length)
    i++;
    //txtScore.Text = score;

    lblQuestion.Text = questions[i];

    radA.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radB.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radC.Text = answers[a];
    a++;
    radD.Text = answers[a];
    a++;

    btnStart.Visible = false;
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
    btnSubmit.Visible = true;
    btnSubmit.Enabled = true;

}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){


    if(getSelectedAnswer().Equals(quizAnswers[i]))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        score++;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
        btnStart.Visible = true;
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnStart.Text = "Next";
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
        score--;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
        btnStart.Visible = true;
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnStart.Text = "Next";
    }
}
string getSelectedAnswer()
{
    if (radA.Checked)
    return radA.Text.ToString();
    if (radB.Checked)
    return radB.Text.ToString();
    if (radC.Checked)
    return radC.Text.ToString();
    if (radD.Checked)
    return radD.Text.ToString();
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) , my suggestion is make textbox readonly so that user can not modify it, and run the run this loop till the length of questions.